# Which Azure metrics aggregation type returns decimal values?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I am using Azure metrics for evaluation of how healthy my Azure resource is, by collecting its default aggregation type for each metric of a resource. I can see the MetricValue class in the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent.Models namespace of the SDK would return the value of type double for all the Aggregation types.

```
namespace Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent.Models
{
    public class MetricValue
    {
        public MetricValue();
        public MetricValue(DateTime timeStamp, double? average = null, double? minimum = null, double? maximum = null, double? total = null, double? count = null);

        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public double? Average { get; set; }
        public double? Minimum { get; set; }
        public double? Maximum { get; set; }
        public double? Total { get; set; }
        public double? Count { get; set; }
        public virtual void Validate();
    }
}
```

My question here is (considering the double data type), are there actually chances for all the Azure metrics of all services to return decimal values? I can see the count of messages in a service bus metric returns decimal values at times. I do not find specific docs related to my question to get clarified. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking "why did Microsoft choose to use decimal for Count?" ?

Comment: My question is, is there actually a chance for all the metrics of all Azure services to return decimal value? I don't think we get decimal value for "Requests" metric of an Azure function. But the data type specified is double for all the aggregation types.

Answer (score 1):

Because metric can be anything and MetricValue is a general common type/schema which needs to cater all kinds of metrics, some requiring highest possible precision, very high or low values (+ve or -ve), and also to be persisted in the underlying common data store (for example Azure Monitor). Now while some metric may be integer depending on the unit in the  context (for example, when you say my request took 300 milliseconds), some may not (for example, there is 20.57 GB free disk space available). And remember, apart from the inbuilt Azure metrics, there can custom metrics from your application which can be possibly anything under imagination. So, to accommodate enough high precision possible, `double` is the choice. That explains Average, Minimum, Maximum, Total. But then why Count is also `double`, I am not fully sure, but most possibly to accommodate a super high number just in case needed and we are not exhausted with int or long. Or it might be that count within a time window which can be decimal (10.6 request per minute).

Comment: I get Count of messages in a decimal value like 10.68. So can i consider there can be any chance for an integer value metric which we expect can be in decimal too? In your example, you say "request" is 300 milliseconds. As count appears to be in decimal, is there a way "request" can also be returned as a decimal value?

Comment: it might be that count within a time window which can be decimal (10.6 request per minute). What is your log query?

Comment: Here's the reference link that I used to retrieve metric: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/monitor-dotnet-metrics-api/monitor-dotnet-metrics-api/

Comment: Okay I thiink it's because there is time grain in the query like 'timeGrain eq duration'PT5M' which means count in every 5 minutes which may be decimal (10.68 requests in 5 minutes) based on calculation over a larger period.