# Does Peek() method in PeekLock mode lock a Service bus message?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I know we can use Receive() method on PeekLock mode, to Lock the message, process it and finally Complete() it. But, how does Peek() method work on PeekLock mode? Does it lock the message?

```
var client = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient("entity", ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
BrokeredMessage = client.Peek();
```

Also, as a second question, I know we can repeatedly call the Peek() to peek all the Active end messages. But, can Peek() method be used repeatedly to Peek all the dead lettered messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, how does Peek() method work on PeekLock mode? Does it lock the message?

No, `Peek()` does not lock the message regardless of the mode. Mode is applicable to `Receive()` only. Not only that `Peek()` can even return message which are locked by another receiver.

> But, can Peek() method be used repeatedly to Peek all the dead lettered messages?

Yes, deadlettered messages resides in another special queue. You can `Peek()` from it just like a normal queue.

Also to improve throughput, you can use `PeekBatch` instead of `Peek`.

In summary, `Peek` is the API for message browsing/diagnostics purpose. You may want to give the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-browsing) a quick read.

Note: The peek operation on a non-partitioned entity always returns the oldest message, but not on a partitioned entity. Instead, it returns the oldest message in one of the partitions whose message broker responded first. There is no guarantee that the returned message is the oldest one across all partitions.

Comment: Thank you so much @krishg! From your answer to my second question, will calling Peek() repeatedly peek all the messages in a partitioned queue? I know the QueueClient tracks the last peeked sequence number and so it gives unique messages for a conventional queue. But how about partitioned queue? During the first Peek() call, any message broker can respond and send its message. So, how can we achieve Peeking all the messages of a partitioned queue?

Comment: Even for partitioned queue, your listener/receiver will check for messages in all fragments. So, solution is same you can browse through messages by calling Peek() repeatedly. You can do a quick test to prove that.

Comment: Yea it worked during few tests. But according to the documentation, any message broker can respond first. So if the responded message broker's message's Sequence number is higher than few other messages in other message brokers, then those messages with Sequence number lesser than the one we just peeked will never be considered. Can this also be a case? Because the client tracks the last peeked sequence number and next it peeks the sequence number greater than before. Though I've never got this test case covered, this is based on my theoretical understanding.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation you are referring? Since the receiver will round robin through all fragments, I think it peeks from all partitions independently. And also, for Peek(), it does not care about any other competing listeners. Also to improve throughput, you can use 'PeekBatch' instead of 'Peek'.

Comment: Here's the doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-partitioning#how-it-works Here it says "The peek operation on a non-partitioned entity always returns the oldest message, but not on a partitioned entity. Instead, it returns the oldest message in one of the partitions whose message broker responded first. There is no guarantee that the returned message is the oldest one across all partitions." If its not the oldest across the partitions, Peek() cannot receive the older messages as Peek() works from lower sequence number to higher when browsing.

Comment: Yes you are right on the broker part (oldest message). But regarding sequence number, AFAIK, it is issued relative to the partition as per https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing. Since this topic was not part of the original question here, I would suggest you to create a new question specific to this.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your answer and this thread gave a clear understanding. Can you try to answer this question when possible : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458999/which-azure-metrics-aggregation-type-returns-decimal-values?noredirect=1#comment113979285_64458999

Answer (score 1):

`Peek` does not lock the message. In fact, Peek doesn't even know any detail about the lock. This is what the docs say:

> *Peek also returns messages that were locked and are currently being processed by other receivers. However, because Peek returns a disconnected snapshot, the lock state of a message can't be observed on peeked messages.*

You can check this by accessing the messages's lock property, such as `LockedUntilUtc`. This will return you an exception `InvalidOperationException`.

The answer for your second question is simply "Yes". You can browse messages both active messages and dead-letters.